# how to get fields of method in QDOX 2.0 API?

Tags: qdox

In QDOX 2.0 API, how to get fields (variables) declared/used within a method?

com.thoughtworks.qdox.model.JavaMethod do not have method like getFields() or something alike to get the list of fields under method.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

QDox doesn't provide access to the elements inside the method body, you can only get the complete codeblock.